# Running an IME with Qt Widget

Tags: qt, cjk, qt6, qlineedit, ime

I can't get an IME to work with a Qt Widget (the goal is to write Japanese characters with a western keyboard). I can't activate the IME in the taskbar when I launch a simple test software (a `QLineEdit` in a `QMainWidow`).

I set the `Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled` to true for the `QLineEdit` widget only, then also for the `QMainWindow`. This has no effect.

The IME works fine with a text editor like Xed.

I'm using:

- Linux Mint 21.1
- Qt Creator 11.02
- Qt 6.4.0

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

#### Qt5

The file `libfcitxplatforminputcontextplugin.so` is required in the directory:

```
[...]/Qt/5.xxx.xxx/gcc_64/plugins/platforminputcontexts
```